# Edit same emails in csv file

Tags: bash, shell

I need to edit csv file.
Task is to change first letter of name and surname to uppercase (name surname or name Surname -> Name Surname), I have finished it.
But another task is to set emails. Need to set email using name and surname, example ( John Wick -> jwick@mail.com), AND if there another same email (Joe Wick -> jwick@mail.com), need to change second to jwick@mail**1**.com... if there another one to jwick@mail**2**.com.

**name_new** it is a edit names
**email_new**  edited email (I haven't finished it)
**check_same** is array there I append all emails (without @mail.ru and number)

```
while IFS="," read id  name location job email
do
   unset name_new
   unset email_new   
   declare -a check_same
   

    if [ "$id" == id ]; then
        echo "${id},${name},${email}"
        continue
    fi

    for n in $name; do
        if [ -z "$name_new" ]
        then

            name_new=${n^}            #name
            email_new=${n:0:1}        #first letter of name
            email_new=${email_new,,}  #lowercase letter
        else
            name_new+=" ${n^}"        #surname
            email_new+=${n,,}         #lowercase surname for email
            check_same+=($email_new)  #append
         
           #need to add domain @mail.ru or 1@mail.ru 2@mail.ru if it not unique mail name
          
         fi
    done

    echo "${id},${name_new},${email_new}"
done < member.csv
```

right now statement:

```
sysadmin@server:~/final$ ./final_1
id,name,email
1,Andriy Marashnichenko,amarashnichenko   (need change to amarashnichenko@mail.ru)
**2,Peter Yan,pyan**        (need change to pyan@mail.ru)
3,Wesley Brown,wbrown
4,Shuhrat Yusupov,syusupov
5,Nina Kravets,nkravets
6,Inna Shin,ishin
**7,Peter Yan,pyan**         (need change to pyan1@mail.ru)
....
**34,Pavel Yan,pyan**    (pyan2@mail.ru)
```

I hope you got it.
I tryied much more things. I tired to solve it, I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Using a shell loop for this is almost certainly the wrong approach.  There are situations where you genuinely cannot avoid it, but this does not seem to be one of those.  See also [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) on our sibling site [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

My suggestion would be to switch to Awk, which has rather similar features for examining and manipulating text.

```sh
awk -F "," 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }
  NR>1{
    n = split($2, name, / /); newname = "";
    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
        newname = newname " " toupper(substr(name[i], 1, 1)) tolower(substr(name[i], 2))
    if ($2 ~ /(^| )[a-z]/) {
        $2 = substr(newname, 2)
    }
    mailid = tolower(substr(name[1], 1, 1)) tolower(name[n])
    suffix = 0
    while (seen[mailid suffix])
        ++suffix
    ++seen[mailid suffix]
    mailid = mailid (suffix > 0 ? suffix : "")
    $NF = mailid "@mail.ru"
} 1' member.csv
```

Your requirements were also somewhat inconsistent, but at least I hope this should steer you in the right direction.  The output for the sample data you provided is

```
id,name,email
1,Andriy Marashnichenko,amarashnichenko@example.ru
2,Peter Yan,pyan@example.ru
3,Wesley Brown,wbrown@example.ru
4,Shuhrat Yusupov,syusupov@example.ru
5,Nina Kravets,nkravets@example.ru
6,Inna Shin,ishin@example.ru
7,Peter Yan,pyan1@example.ru
34,Pavel Yan,pyan2@example.ru
```

(except I replaced `mail.ru` with `example.ru` here to avoid exposing the inboxes of innocent third parties to new spam).

In some more detail, `NR>1` skips the header line (instead of comparing against `id`, we trust the first line to be the header). We keep an array `seen` where each address is kept with a numeric suffix to somewhat simplify the subsequent logic. (The first user will thus be stored as `flastname0` in the `seen` associative array, the second as `flastname1` etc).  The rest should be fairly obvious; `substr("something", start, length)` extracts a substring and `tolower("STRING")` produces a lowercased version.  We split the second field (the names) on whitespace into the array `name` and then piece them back together into a proper-cased version.

Comment: Thank you very much, I executed your script, but mail displayed not correctly (displays 118@mail.ru, 882@mail.ru....)

Comment: And could you help to edit my script? because I couldn't understand your script it is difficult

Comment: It works correctly for me; demo: https://ideone.com/BNlFs1. I assume you can figure out the basics of Awk from a beginners' tutorial; is there something in particular you would like me to explain?

Comment: will be cool if you modify my ugly code :)

Comment: Your requirements are incongruent and it will be hard to backport this to an older version of Bash.  If you have version 5+ you can use associative arrays similar to what I don in Awk here. If you can edit your question to clear up the oddities (should we add @mail.ru to the end or not? Do you have examples of incorrectly capitalized names?) and explain where you are stuck, maybe it won't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```sh
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}
    NR > 1 {
        email = $3 (count[$3] ? count[$3] : "") "@mail.ru"
        count[$3]++
        $3 = email
    }
    {print}
' member.csv
```